# Regex for CSVs, explanation of what is going on.

Tags: java, regex

OK so I've looked through various answers on how to break up a csv String with included quotes using the inbuilt functionality. I've gone through and tested various answers, and what I've found is that the following string works:

```
"\"([^\"]*)\"" + //Zero or more not-quoted characters inside of quotes
"|" + //or
"(?<=,|^)" + 
"([^,]*)" + //all characters not delimiter
"(?=,|$)"  //delimiter or end of string
```

I'm trying to work out for my own knowledge what is going on, especially with the uncommented section above. Can anyone provide an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<=,|^)` and `(?=,|$)` are regular expression assertions to implement what is called (respectively) positive lookbehind and lookahead.

Your regex (removed the java string-building quotes and concats for clarity) matches:

```
"([^"]*)"  // 0+ not-quote characters inside of quotes (captured)
|          // OR 
      ([^,]*)          // any 0+ character which is not , (captured) only if
             (?<=,|^)  // preceded by , or at start of line AND
             (?=,|$)   // followed by , or at end of line
```

These constructs are called zero-width because they do not consume characters in the test string.  Negative versions of the assertions also exists, using `!` instead of `=`, so that  `(?<!,|^)` and `(?!,|$)` would mean match only if expression is NOT preceded (lookbehind) or followed (lookahead) by assertion.

More info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).